# Solving data skew in SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a SPARK SQL code that joins a fact table and dimension table. Join condition leads to data skew as one of the result combination will have huge data compared to others. In scala , I think this can be solved with

```
    partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(160))
```

But this works only on RDD and not on schemaRDD.

Is there an equivalent to this ?

Here is how my code looks like

```
    sqlContext.sql("select product_category,shipment_item_id,shipment_amount from shipments_fact f left outer join product_category pc on f.category_code = pc.category_code")
```

Request help...

Comment: If you just want to increase the number of partitions for the shuffle process, you can use `sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=<...>")`. By default, the vale of this conf is 200.

Comment: does this work on spark 1.0.1 ? I know it is there in 1.1.0 ...Is there an alternate ?

Comment: It should work in 1.0.1.

Comment: thanks...I tested it and it did work fine....

Comment: In spark 1.0.0 I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``INSERT'' expected but identifier SET found`